# How to correctly use WHERE when making an INNER JOIN with JOOQ?

Tags: java, spring, jooq

I've just set up JOOQ on a Spring Boot Project along a Postgres Database and I'm loving it! I don't think I will be using ORMs after this, but I'm really having problems with no so simple CRUD queries.

At this point I don't know if my JOOQ query is badly written or If I'm not handling the return types as expected.

I'm basically trying to make a simple **INNER JOIN** between two tables:

-

```
          QUESTIONS TABLE

+----+--------+----------------+-------------+
| question_id |  question_body | question_answer 
+----+--------+----------------+-------------+
| P_KEY  INT  |  TEXT          |  JSON       |
|             |                |             |
+----+--------+----------------+-------------+
```

```
            TESTS CONTENT

+----------------+-------------+
| question_id    | test_id     |
+----------------+-------------+
|P_KEY - INT     | FKEY - INT  |
+----------------+-------------+
```

With those two tables I'm trying to translate this SQL Query

```
SELECT *
FROM questions q
INNER JOIN tests_content t ON q.question_id = t.question_id 
WHERE t.test_id = 1007;
```

...Into a a JOOQ query. I've tried a handful methods, including the relevant ones in the docs and a few that I found here on SO. Basically my JOOQ queries look like these:

```
public Result<Record> queryMethod(){
    return dslContext.select().
        from(questions).
        join(testsContent).
        using(testsContent.QUESTION_ID).
        where(testsContent.QUESTION_ID.eq(1007)).fetch();
}
```

But I can't make this to work! I don't know if I have to create a custom POJO to handle the result, if my JOOQ syntax is wrong, or If I'm not handling the return type correctly.

Another thing that worries me is that one field of the questions table is of JSON type, and maybe that could be a problem too.

I'd be very grateful If somebody could give me a hand with this.

Thanks for reading!

---

EDIT 1:

Tried with fetching into a custom POJO but the query returns an empty array at request.

JOOQ Query:

```
public List<JoinQuestionsTest> query(){
    return dslContext.select().from(questions)
        .join(testsContent).using(testsContent.QUESTION_ID)
        .where(testsContent.QUESTION_ID.eq(1007))
        .fetchInto(JoinQuestionsTest.class);
}
```

POJO code:

```
import org.jooq.JSON;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class JoinQuestionsTest {
    private int question_id;
    private int test_id;
    private String question_body;
    private JSON question_answer;
}
```

---

EDIT 2: Adding the Logger Code of the query:

```
DEBUG 2786 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener:
Executing query: 
    select "public"."questions"."question_id", "public"."questions"."question_body", "public"."questions"."question_explanation", "public"."questions"."question_answer", "public"."tests_content"."question_id", "public"."tests_content"."test_id" 
    from "public"."questions"
    join "public"."tests_content" 
    using ("question_id")
    where "public"."tests_content"."question_id" = ?
DEBUG 2786 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener: 
-> with bind values: 
    select "public"."questions"."question_id", "public"."questions"."question_body", "public"."questions"."question_explanation", "public"."questions"."question_answer", "public"."tests_content"."question_id", "public"."tests_content"."test_id" 
    from "public"."questions" 
    join "public"."tests_content"
    using ("question_id") 
    where "public"."tests_content"."question_id" = 1007
DEBUG 2786 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener: Fetched result: 
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
|question_id|question_body|question_explanation|question_answer|question_id|test_id|
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
Fetched row(s)           : 0
2020-08-27 13:27:11.617  WARN 2786 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved 
[org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "favicon.ico"]
```

---

EDIT 3:

It seems that the Problem is with the WHERE clause. I removed it from the JOOQ code and now the query works...

```
return dslContext.select(
                testsContent.QUESTION_ID,
                testsContent.TEST_ID,
                questions.QUESTION_BODY,
                questions.QUESTION_EXPLANATION,
                questions.QUESTION_ANSWER
).from(questions).join(testsContent).using(testsContent.QUESTION_ID).fetchInto(JoinQuestionsTest.class);
```

I also adjusted the POJO because it seems that JSON data is handled as a String and not with the included JSON type(I don't get why this latter exists). The POJO now looks like this:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class JoinQuestionsTest {
    private int question_id;
    private int test_id;
    private String question_body;
    private String question_explanation;
    private String question_answer;
}
```

Currently experimenting/researching how to make the .where() method work.

Comment: Hello! What does "But I can't make this to work!" mean? Are you seeing a compilation error, a SQL error, or wrong SQL being executed, or something completely different?

Comment: _"the query returns an empty array"_ - okay, that's something. Now we need to take a look at the generated query. Jooq automatically logs every query at the Debug level, so either enable debug logging to see what's being generated, or just write out your query to the console with a "getSQL()" call. Does the query look like what you expected?

Comment: @PetrJaneček Hi, thanks for answering. I've got an empty array as a response when making the query via request (Spring Boot REST API). I know that JOOQ and the API are correctly working because first I tried simple queries, but now when trying complex ones, as a simple inner join, I get an empty array.

Comment: ...we still need to find out *where* things are going wrong. It could be jooq (that's unlikely, but bugs do happen), so we need to check the generated query. Then I'd run the query manually against the DB to see whether it *should* return anything or not. If yes, the problem will be in mapping. If no, the problem is in the data. Check every step, go slowly, or simply debug the application and go line-by-line. You'll eventually see something you did not expect, and that's where your problem is. Your jOOQ code looks OK.

Comment: OK! Now I see the query and indeed it returns 0 results. The problem is in the data. Look into your tables and check why. Is the DB empty? Did you pick an incorrect id? Maybe you inserted the data, but forgot to commit the transaction?

Comment: @PetrJaneček Thanks for your support and for pointing the logger out! I had no idea about it. It definitely helped me to see that the query is alright (I put the log above)  as you said, but still throws an empty array! I even adjusted the SELECT fields on JOOQ and also the POJO with the according changes, but the problem persists. I tried ignoring the JSON column as well, but still nothing. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Your query states: WHERE t.test_id = 1007; but your test beneath it suggests you're querying for Question_Id eq(1007). Are you sure you're using the WHERE clause on the correct field?

Comment: @RobEvans You are right! What a big mistake! Fixing the POJO and adjusting the JOOQ query to ```.where(testsContent.TEST_ID.eq(1007))``` fixed the problem! Thank you for reading my question! You just saved me from hours of debugging. If you want, publish this as the answer and I'll mark it. Cheers!